# What are the pros and cons of running LineageOS?

Tags: custom-roms, lineageos

Specifically, do Google apps (Maps, Play store) and third-party apps (Skype, Viber, etc.) work as reliably with it as they would with, say, Android One?

Or is it more of a hit-and-miss situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pros:**

- you can run latest android OS on your device even after your manufacturer stops security patch/ os upgrades.
- Experience pure stock android.
- Nowadays builds are mostly stable with less bugs.
  You don't have any bloatware on your device.

(Download from sites like xda, and official builds are best, for which developers release nightly, after bug removal.)

- By rooting, you can take over control on everything on your device.

**Cons:**

- If the developer stop support, you need to switch to another build (pixel experience, havoc etc)
- You need to unlock bootloader which is a security issue.
- Rooting also a security issue, some banking apps doesn't work on rooted device (This can be solved using MagiskHide method from Magisk Manager).